# FAST Search duplicates results

Tags: managed-metadata, duplicate

We are facing the following problem: We have created a custom document library with a managed metadata field and it seems FAST Search duplicates the result, i.e., in the result page for each result item a label "Duplicate(2)" appears under the item. When we click on this label, two instance of the same document are shown. When the managed metadata is empty, it seems the issue does not occur.

Are we missing any configuration ? Is there any suggestion on how to solve this ?

Thank you